# Locking mechanism is required for static list or variables?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, static, thread-safety

I know static variable or collection is shared, across the threads, at most single memory address is created for variable, and it's state will be persistent, across the threads.

static int count =0

thread 1 --> count++

thread 2 --> diplay count -->1

thread 3 --> count--

thread 1 --> display count -->0

my question, locking mechanism is required for static collections? below is the static collection and locking mechanism.

```
public static List<ConnectionManager> ServerConnections = new List<ConnectionManager>();
lock (Global.ServerConnections)
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes. You need a lock because Static != Thread safe. This applies to your `count` variable too.

Just because a variable is static that doesn't make it thread safe. Multiple threads can still access it at the exact same time which causes concurrency issues.

There is no thread safety to anything by default, it has to be designed to be thread safe.

Also take a look at the [**`ConcurrentBag<T>`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you need just thread safety you can use C# concurrent collections, but if you want some synchronization (like several actions upon a collection inside one thread to be executed without any impact of other threads) you need locking.

Actually you also need to take care of your variables, `count++` and `count--` are not thread safe. Use `Interlocked` or any other mechanism to ensure thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

It belongs to how you use the collection and how you instatiate it. If you instantiate it from different threads you should gurantee that only one thread instatiate it. Because with badluck more threads try instatiation at the same time. The [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/en-en/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class implemented in .Net is for this purpose and makes it easy to instantiate thread safe and lazy. Futher you need to lock your collection in any case of operation you wanna do. Insert, Remove, Iterate etc. are all not thread safe. Read about concurrentDictionary etc. for more information about thread safe collections.